# Как осуществить подключение в данном случае, и доступ к контенту этого скрипта?

Tags: javascript

Утрированно реализовал свою задачу ! Есть пять файлов : 
**1.html :**

```html
<a href="2.html?numb:1">PAGE 1</a>
<a href="2.html?numb:2">PAGE 2</a>
```

в этом файле две ссылки, которые перенаправляют **на одну** страницу, разница между ними лишь в параметрах, которые передаются при загрузки этой (**'2.html'**) страницы.
**2.html :**

```js
appendScript() ;

function appendScript(){

    let scriptName = parseURL(),
        scriptObj = document.createElement('script') ;

    scriptObj.setAttribute('src', scriptName + '.js') ;

    document.head.appendChild( scriptObj ) ;

};

function parseURL(){

    let url = location.href ;
        params = '' ;

    url.split('/')
       .forEach(function(urlPath){
            if(urlPath.indexOf('?')!==-1){
                params = urlPath ;
            } ;
       }) ;


    let res = params.slice( params.indexOf('?') + 1 )  ;

    return res.split(':')[1] ;

};
```

На данной страничке подключен простой скрипт (в данном случае он упрощён, для примера) который парсит УРЛ, выдёргивает параметр, и в соответствии с этим подключает нужный мне скрипт в тэг хэд на страницу 2.html, на этой же страничке (2.хтмл) **после парсинга урла**, и подключения скрипта, подключен внешний скрипт **executionScript.js**, который в данном упрощённом варианте делает всего лишь :

```js
console.log( JSON.stringify( THIS_IS_WHAT_I_NEED_TO_WATCH,null,3)) ;
```

а именно просто выводит сообщение в консоль с содержимым объекта **THIS_IS_WHAT_I_NEED_TO_WATCH**, который содержится в одном из js файлов подключаемых к страничке 2.хтмл!
Суть данного вопроса такова, мне нужно получить контент динамически, Но получается, что скрипт, который я подключаю к страничке 2.html , точнее его содержимое не видно файлу **executionScript.js**, поэтому при выполнении этого файла я получаю ошибку, данная проблема в целом легко устраняется с помощью асинхронной загрузки содержимого файла **executionScript.js**, например :

```js
hackTimeout( printJson ) ;

function printJson(){
    console.log( JSON.stringify( THIS_IS_WHAT_I_NEED_TO_WATCH ,null,3)) ;
} ;

function hackTimeout( fn ){
    setTimeout( fn, 40 ) ;
} ;
```

Но имхо даже я спустя время прочитая этот код бы запутался, что к чему , и зачем, к тому-же разумеется что модель, представленная мною утрированна, в реальности файлы выполняют гораздо больше действий, но суть от этого не меняется, в общем, если у кого-то есть мысли по этому поводу, грамотной реализации, буду рад услышать ! Разумеется из тех, кому не лень было дочитывать до конца, спасибо! p.s.: данное приложение полностью оффлайновое, без бэкэнда,аякс запросов и т. д., и вариант с `scriptObj.async = true;` я уже пробовал, всё равно не работает!

Comment: Покажите, где и как вы подключаете `executionScript.js`. Это важно!

Comment: ну если быть точным, то перед закрывающим тегом </body> в файле 2.html

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите эту информацию в вопросе! Проблема в том, что `executionScript.js` загружается\выполняется быстрее, чем `document.head.appendChild( scriptObj )`. Решение - дождаться загрузки `document.head.appendChild( scriptObj )`, потом загружать `executionScript.js`. Дождаться загрузки можно с помощью `scriptObj .onLoad = function(){}`.